# Cant take photos using Android Developer tutorial

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to use the following tutorial on [Taking Photos Simply](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html)

I hope I will not get too many downvotes, but I am trying to make this tutorial succeed since yesterday(a beginner), so I wish you can help me solve that:

```
This is my current code:
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    static final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 1;
    String mCurrentPhotoPath;
    private Bitmap mImageBitmap;
    private ImageView mImageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button takePhoto = (Button) findViewById(R.id.take_photo);
    }
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }


    public void dispatchTakePictureIntent(View v) {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File

            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                        "com.example.android.fileprovider",
                        photoFile);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
            }
        }
    }


    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }
}
```

and the button part of the layout xml:

```
 <Button
        android:text="Take Photo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
        android:id="@+id/take_photo"
        android:onClick="dispatchTakePictureIntent" />
```

However, when I click the button in the app, it crashed with the following logcat:

```
        FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.test.testapp, PID: 11174
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4764)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19844)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5349)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4764) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19844) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5349) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703) 
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.test.testapp/files/Pictures/JPEG_20170122_114322_-6447522201.jpg
        at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:711)
        at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:400)
        at com.test.testapp.MainActivity.dispatchTakePictureIntent(MainActivity.java:55)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4764) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19844) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5349) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
```

Thanks

Comment: Well what is the problem you encounter?

Comment: It's not the button that causes the error but the `FileProvider` config. Could you include the `file_paths.xml` (or whatever you named it) in your question?

Comment: This is the file_paths.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <external-path name="my_images" path="Android/data/com.example.package.name/files/Pictures" />
</paths>
So perhaps the mistake is that I should name is com.test.testapp?

Comment: @comparter Change `com.example.package.name` to whatever your package name is (the one declared in your gradle file as `applicationId`).

Comment: Changed it, still the same errors, so annoying

Answer (score 0):

Try `<external-files-path name="my_images" path="Pictures" />` in your `file_paths.xml` file instead of the `<external-path>` that you are using.